# Codigniter validation for exact maching of string

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I want to setup my validation rules in codeigniter such as a field starts with character 'P' or 'S', other wise it is invalid. How can I do that using Codigniter validation library?

```
Test Case 1: input: A145874 ------- invalid Must start with P or S
Test Case 2: input: P258741 -------   valid
Test Case 3: input: P45KK91 ------- invalid Must not contain Letters in other positions rather the first one.
Test Case 4: input: S457821 -------   valid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write a custom validation rule. Something like this:

```
public function check_first_char($str) {
    $first_char = substr($str, 0, 1);
    if ($first_char != 'P' || $first_char != 'S') {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_first_char', 'The %s field must begin with P or S!');
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Then you would add that validation rule like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('field_name', 'Field Name', 'callback_check_first_char');
```

[The documentation explains it all pretty clearly](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks).

Comment: why you are using the callback_ before the function name?

Comment: @Alvi_1987: As the documentation states: `To invoke a callback just put the function name in a rule, with "callback_" as the rule prefix.` So the validation rule is the function name, with `callback_` before it. Check out the link in my answer if you want to read more.